# Camelize a php string

Tags: php

How to convert this type of php string to camel case?

```
$string = primary-getallgroups-sys
```

I've tried but just found different solutions to camelize a string with spaces. Like ucword($string), but it just capitalize the first word. When i add a delimeter of hyphen (-), it gives error.

Comment: Show your existing code and the error you get, plus your desired output for your example string

Comment: I just want to convert this string to a string like

$string = Primary-Getallgroups-sys

It just gives blank page after passing a delimeter to that.

$string = primary-getallgroups-sys
$string = ucwords($string);    // Primary-getallgroups-sys

If I use a delimeter like
$string = primary-getallgroups-sys
$string = ucwords($string,"-");    // Shows nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = 'primary-getallgroups-sys';

// split string by '-'
$words = explode('-', $string);

// make a strings first character uppercase
$words = array_map('ucfirst', $words);

// join array elements with '-'
$string = implode('-', $words);

echo $string; // is now Primary-Getallgroups-Sys
```

Comment: Thanku.
Plus is there any way to convert "getallgroups" to camel case like "GetAllGroups"?

Comment: There is no way to convert `getallgroups` into camel case. As the code cannot differentiate between English words. You need to specify where it has to break.

Comment: Okay.
Is there any way to do the same process to a variable in bash shell script?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function to convert these types of string to camel cases.

Try this:

```
<?php
// CONVERT STRING TO CAMEL CASE SEPARATED BY A DELIMITER
function convertToCamel($str, $delim){
    $exploded_str = explode($delim, $str);
    $exploded_str_camel = array_map('ucwords', $exploded_str);
    return implode($delim, $exploded_str_camel);
}

$string = 'primary-getallgroups-sys';

echo convertToCamel($string, '-'); // Answer

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact camel case is more like this: `iAmCamelCased`.

And this is mixed case: `IAmMixedCased`.

**@sundas-mushtaq Also note that hyphens will break your code if used in symbol names (like in functions or variables).**

To camelize, use this:

```
function camelize($word, $delimiter){
    $elements = explode($delimiter, $word);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($elements); $i++) {
        if (0 == $i) {
            $elements[$i] = strtolower($elements[$i]);
        } else {
            $elements[$i] = strtolower($elements[$i]);
            $elements[$i] = ucwords($elements[$i]);
        }
    }

    return implode('', $elements);
}
```

And to mixify, use this :

```
function mixify($word, $delimiter){
    $word = strtolower($word);
    $word = ucwords($word, $delimiter);

    return str_replace($delimiter, '', $word);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From Symfony

```
function camelize(string $string): string
{
    return lcfirst(str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\x7f-\xff]++/', ' ', $string))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// if you want to camelize first word also, remove lcfirst call

function camelize($string) {
    $tokens = array_map("ucFirst", explode("_", $string)) ;
    return lcfirst(implode("",$tokens));
}
```